# How can I get bold Greek letters with mathptmx?

Tags: symbols, bold

I'm currently using these packages in my document:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

But when I try to use:

```
\boldsymbol{\sigma}
```

As and example, well, nothing happens. It's not bold. I've also tried `\mathbf` and such. But nothing happens.

I don't know if it is because I'm using the "Times New Roman"-like package ?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Yes, the reason is `mathptmx`; try `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, if you have an up-to-date TeX distribution.

Comment: The documentation for the mathptmx package says:   · There are no bold math fonts, and \boldmath has no effect.

Comment: ^^
So what you are saying is, that there is nothing I can do about it ?
The \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `\mbox{\boldmath$\sigma$}` should work.  I use this all the time for bold Greek letters.  If it works for you, I will make it an answer.

Comment: ^^
Nope, it does not :/
I'm just doing:

    \begin{equation}
\mbox{\boldmath$\sigma$} =\frac{\mathbf{j}}{\mathbf{E}}, \label{eq:3.1}
\end{equation}

Comment: You can ping a person directly by putting a `@` in front of their name, like in `@DenverDang`.

Comment: load amsfonts that is what is doing it for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a last resort, over-printing (or under-printing) as a method to simulate boldness (or fake bold) is an option using the [`contour` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/contour). It may come in handy when there is no bold version of a font/symbol available:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\usepackage{array,contour}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl@{\quad}>{\contourlength{0.01em}}l}
\verb|\sigma|: & $\sigma$ & $\sigma$ \\
\verb|\contour[1]{red}{$\sigma$}|: & \contour[1]{red}{$\sigma$} & \contour[1]{red}{$\sigma$} \\
\verb|\contour[10]{black}{$\sigma$}|: & \contour[10]{black}{$\sigma$} & \contour[10]{black}{$\sigma$} \\
\verb|\contour{black}{$\sigma$}|: & \contour{black}{$\sigma$} & \contour{black}{$\sigma$} \\
\verb|\contour*{black}{$\sigma$}|: & \contour*{black}{$\sigma$} & \contour*{black}{$\sigma$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The default interface is `\contour[<number>]{<color>}{<stuff>}` that prints `<number>` copies of `<stuff>` *under* `<stuff>` using colour `<color>`. The default is 16 repetitions if none are specified, while the starred-version `\contour*` prints 32. `\contourlength{<len>}` sets the radius of the under-printing. The two column above are default (`0.03em`) and `0.01em`.

To make the under-printing more obvious/clear, here's a close-up view of the above contours at the default setting:

[image]

And, for `\contourlength{0.01em}`:

[image]

Comment: And there we have it :)
A bit of a workaround, but it works :)

Thank you :P

Comment: `\newcommand{\contourbbms}[1]{\text{\contour[2]{black}{$#1$}}}` if you use it in equations for one symbol, you'd better create a new command. You should put the `contour` command in `\text{}`. Then you use it as `$\contourbbms{\sigma}+\sigma=2\sigma$`. But I run `xelatex` twice then I get the bold symbol. Anyway it works.

Answer (score 14):

With `newtx` you can get bold math symbols; the text font is very similar to what you'd get with `mathptmx` and the math fonts are surely much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\Sigma\sigma$

$\bm{\Sigma}\bm{\sigma}$

$\sum\bm{\sum}\displaystyle\sum\bm{\sum}$
\end{document}
```

Note that `\boldsymbol` provided by the `amsbsy` package is to be considered obsolete as `\bm` is much better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have `amsfonts` loaded:

```
An ex­tended set of fonts for use in math­e­mat­ics, in­clud­ing: 
ex­tra math­e­mat­i­cal sym­bols; black­board bold let­ters (up­per­case only); frak­tur let­ters; 
sub­script sizes of bold math italic and **bold Greek let­ters**; 
sub­script sizes of large sym­bols such as sum and prod­uct; 
added sizes of the Com­puter Modern small caps font; 
cyril­lic fonts (from the Univer­sity of Wash­ing­ton); Euler math­e­mat­i­cal fonts.
```

Even though you say it didn't work, it is working fine on my end.

```
 \begin{equation} \mbox{\boldmath$\sigma$} =\frac{\mathbf{j}}{\mathbf{E}}, \label{eq:3.1} \end{equation}
```

produced:

[image]

as you can see I just added real quick to a document I am working on.

Here is a regular sigma next to it.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the same font?

Comment: @Werner I have pxfonts loaded.  amsfonts is doing it I believe.

Comment: This is what I have: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/69570825.png/ and http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/84259646.png/ where I have it with the "Times new roman" font, and just standard. There is clearly a difference.

Comment: @DenverDang load `amsfonts`