# The equation is too long to fit in the beamer frame, but split environment does not work

Tags: beamer, equations, line-breaking

The main code is as follow:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Householder Transformation}

\begin{equation}
%\onslide<1->
\mathop{
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \times & \times &\times \\
        \times & \times &\times \\
        \times & \times &\times \\
        \times & \times &\times 
    \end{pmatrix}
}_{A}
%\onslide<2->
\xrightarrow{(1:4,1:3)}
\mathop{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
    \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
    \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
    \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}
}_{Q_{1}A}
%\onslide<3->
\xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)}
\begin{split}
\mathop{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \times & \times & \times \\
    0 & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
    0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes \\
    0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}
}_{Q_{1}A}
%\onslide<4->
\xrightarrow{(3:4,3:3)}
\mathop{
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \times & \times & \times \\
    0 & \times & \times \\
    0 & 0 & \mythickertimes \\
    0 & 0 & \boldsymbol{0} 
    \end{pmatrix}
}_{Q_{1}A}
%\onslide<5->
\xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)}
    R.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
```

and the new \mythickertimes is defined as follow：

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\mythickertimes}{ \tikz[baseline=-.55ex] \node [inner sep=0pt,cross out,draw,line width=1pt,minimum size=1ex] (a) {};}
```

and the screwed effect is displayed by the following picture:

[image]

How can I get my equation like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of enclosing the `pmatrix` environments in `\mathop` directives? Do you just want a bit of extra spacing around the matrices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use any of the line-break-able display math environments offered by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). Below I've used `alignat`, but you could manage with `gather` or `align` as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\mythickertimes}{\boldsymbol{\times}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Householder Transformation}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \underset{A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times & \times \\
      \times & \times & \times \\
      \times & \times & \times \\
      \times & \times & \times 
    \end{pmatrix}}
  & \xrightarrow{(1:4,1:3)} &
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}}
  & \xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)} \\
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times & \times \\
      0 & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}}
  & \xrightarrow{(3:4,3:3)} &
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times & \times \\
      0 & \times & \times \\
      0 & 0 & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & 0 & \boldsymbol{0} 
    \end{pmatrix}}
  & \xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)}
  R.
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To display the matrix operations sequentially using an overlay, you can use `\onslide`: <s>Note that you have to specify the overlay separately for each cell within the `alignat` environment:</s>

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\mythickertimes}{\boldsymbol{\times}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Householder Transformation}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \underset{A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times &\times \\
      \times & \times &\times \\
      \times & \times &\times \\
      \times & \times &\times 
    \end{pmatrix}}
  & \onslide<2->{\xrightarrow{(1:4,1:3)} &
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}}}
  & \onslide<3->{\xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)} \\
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times & \times \\
      0 & \mythickertimes & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & \boldsymbol{0} & \mythickertimes 
    \end{pmatrix}}}
  & \onslide<4->{\xrightarrow{(3:4,3:3)} &
  \underset{Q_1 A}{\begin{pmatrix}
      \times & \times & \times \\
      0 & \times & \times \\
      0 & 0 & \mythickertimes \\
      0 & 0 & \boldsymbol{0} 
    \end{pmatrix}}}
  & \onslide<5->{\xrightarrow{(2:4,2:3)}
  R.}
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works well. But I have another problem when I want display matrices one by one by removing the % before \onslide. It just has partial effect. @Werner

Comment: @CodingTheLife: See my updated answer with some discussion around how to display the content on different slides.

Comment: @Werner: The update solution works very well. Thanks. But I have another two questions. First, Why we repeat the \onslide<x-> twice? Does the onslide command after align point (also column point), i.e. "&" or newline, i.e. "\\" , lose its function? Second, the difference between \boldsymbol{\times} and \times is not obvious. In my code the \mythickertimes which other people suggest looks well, but it's complicate. Is there other simpler solution?

Comment: @CodingTheLife: (1) Typically you cannot let macro arguments span `&`. However, as @Mico noted, this is handled properly in `alignat*`, so there's no need. (2) Using a macro is ideal, since you can update it to suit your needs, however complicated. So if you enjoy the output, stick with it. Alternatively you could consider using [`contour`](http://ctan.org/pkg/contour), which overprints the character multiple times with minor offsets. See [How can I get bold Greek letters with `mathptmx`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117083/5764)