# How to make a subscript in bold for a table? \small {\textbf{$df_1$}}

Tags: tables, bold

I want to make a subscript and bold it.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
     \small {\textbf{F}}
     & \small {\textbf{$df_1$}} & \small {\textbf{$df_2$}}
     & \small {\textbf{Sig.}}\\
     \midrule
    2.016 & 3 & 36 & 0.129 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried this:

```
 & \small {\textbf{df_1$}} & \small {\textbf{df_2$}}
```

is working, but with error:

```
Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ) must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ … $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.
```

Comment: Use `$\boldsymbol{df_2}$` or `\boldmath$df_2$\unboldmath`.

Comment: Or `$\mathbf{df_1}$`.

Comment: @Mico But this makes the font upright, so it does no longer look like math. If it is not math stuff, wouldn't `\textbf{df\textsubscript{2}}` be the cleaner solution?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Given the scant information provided by the OP, I'm assuming it's a table related to a test statistic -- an F-test, to be specific, with information about the two degrees-of-freedom parameters and the test's (lack of) significance in the final column. Since the OP seems fine with **F** and **Sig.** using an upright bold font, I assumed an upright bold font is fine for df1 and df2 as well. However, I may be wrong.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat. Thanks for your reply. I wanted to try `$\boldsymbol{df_2}$`, but it unable to compile in overleaf. Is there any preample I need to add?

Comment: Yes, `amsmath`, e.g. : `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{df_1}$
\end{document}` works. (I should have said this above...)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks a lot. I found that my preample have `\usepackage{mathptmx}` making the `df1` and `df2` not `bold`. I have no idea `\usepackage{mathptmx}` and `\usepackage{amsmath}` cannot use together?

Comment: It doesn't look like it, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117076) for possible workarounds. (I never used `\usepackage{mathptmx}` myself, so I cannot say too much. Please do not get me wrong, but I might say that this shows that it is worthwhile to provide a complete minimal compilable example so that others can test their suggestions... ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks. Can i know the different between `{\boldmath$df_1$\unboldmath}` and `{$\boldsymbol{df_1}$}`? It seemed both output is the same. I can ask a new question if needed

Comment: I do not *exactly* know the (La)TeX core difference but obviously `\boldsymbol{...}` is to be used inside math mode only, while `\boldmath` is usually (always?) used outside and affects all math bits, e.g. `\boldmath Let's talk about $A$ and $B$.\undboldmath` will make both `A` and `B` bold. So the bottom-line is if you want to know the core level differences, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\[ % switch to display math mode -- fewer '$' symbols to type
\begin{array}{@{}cccc@{}} % use 'array', not 'tabular'
    \toprule
       \mathbf{F} & \mathbf{df_1} & \mathbf{df_2} & \mathbf{Sig.}\\
    \midrule
       2.016 & 3 & 36 & 0.129 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Brillant. I am curious, why cannot use `\textbf` in table, but need to use `\mathbf`?

Comment: @aan - To answer your question in depth, I'd have to know more about which text and math fonts you employ in your document. Depending on these font choices, `\textbf` might indeed be more appropriate than `\mathbf`. For Computer Modern (the default text and math font) and the letter combinations in the header cells, the difference is minimal.

Comment: Thanks. I am using `%% Font setup
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{helvet}`

Comment: @aan - Loading `mathptmx` (a Times Roman clone) and then Latin Modern (a Computer Modern clone) makes little sense; you might as well omit the `\usepackage{mathptmx}` instruction. In Latin Modern, the math and text fonts are very similar. Anyway, I thinks it's easier, and far more natural, to write `\mathbf{df_1}` than it is to write `\textbf{df}\textsubscript{\textbf{1}}`. The `1` term is very much a math-type subscript rather than a text-type subscript, isn't it?