# Redefine command chain

Tags: bold, greek, times, renewcommand

I've recently switched to To Times New Roman into my Latex report and I've noticed that bold greek letters are printed awfully when using commands like `\bm{}` or `\boldsymbol{}`. I've turned around the problem accordingly to this great post: [How can I get bold Greek letters with mathptmx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/how-can-i-get-bold-greek-letters-with-mathptmx)

The only problem is that (for example) I have the bold nu defined in multiple ways inside my document like `\bm{\nu}` or `\boldsymbol{\nu}`. In order not to look for every occurrency and change it manually I thought that the most efficient way to do that was to rename all these commands with the same one like this:

```
\renewcommand{\bm{\nu}}{\contourlength{0.01em}\contour[10]{black}{$\nu$}}
\renewcommand{\boldsymbol{\nu}}{\contourlength{0.01em}\contour[10]{black}{$\nu$}}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting errors like: `Command \bm{\nu } undefined.` and `Command \boldsymbol{\nu} undefined.`. Is this operation possible? What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not the way how `\renewcommand` works. Using this approach, you can only redefine the commands `\bm` or `\boldsymbol` as such, but you can't replace strings this way. Why don't you search the two strings `\bm{\nu}` and `\boldsymbol{\nu}` via your text editor and replace them by something like `\mynewnu` and assign your new definition to this new macro?

Comment: Re-reading your question: Do you want this for all greek letters? And only for greek letters?

Comment: mathptmx is very old and predates any reasonable math fonts that match Times being available. Do not use it, use a more reasonable setup such as `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: It is hard to guess the intent of your `\renewcommand` the first argument has to be the name of the command being defined not a complete expression involving multiple commands and braces.