# Replicating an Exquisite Font

Tags: fonts, math-operators, typefaces

This question extends the one here: [An Exquisite Mathematical Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591148/an-exquisite-mathematical-font/591459?noredirect=1#comment1484110_591459) by including the question for constructing a replica of the fonts and symbols included there.

The question is, can a set of LaTeX packages be used to replicate old-timey font-typefaces like:[image]

and

[image]

such that the text and boldness fit the second image while the mathematics in the first image is preferable, *and* the integral symbol looks like the one advertised in the previous question (the link above has images); and where the sums look like

[image].

I've only gotten as far as this example: [image]

using **Steven B. Segletes**' answer from [How to Obtain a Bold Upright Integral Sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign). However, the font text most desired would be like what **@Sebastiano** did in my previous question (amazing job), which is:

[image] because many of the letters like the "n" and the "d" and "a" match while other letters are very close.

Comment: For the bold sum you can use the answers of @egreg: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/how-can-i-get-bold-greek-letters-with-mathptmx and for the integral to me seem very closer to the egreg's answer.

Comment: For the sign integral there are two very nice answers: one it is of Steven B. Segletes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222243/how-to-obtain-a-bold-upright-integral-sign